# Mowing traction

Tags: mowing

I have to mow on a section of yard, by a ditch, that is at a steep angle, too steep for me to mow across with my lawn tractor.  So it needs to be mowed with a walk behind mower.  However, at the steepest part, I am afraid I will wipe out and fall down the incline.  If I were 20, fine, but I am 70.  What do I wear on my feet to give me traction?

Answer (score 2):

If you are afraid of a single misstep do not mow that with a mower of any kind!  Do you own a weed wacker?  Line trimmer?  That is the tool for the job unless you own a scythe, sharpened? I am being silly, I have one that hangs on the wall as an antique, grins.

Forget doing any mowing where 'you just might slip' where the ramifications would be...emergency rooms or whatever.  Hire a neighborhood kid that has a line trimmer and would knock down the grass in that swale.  Make sure he knows how to use that tool and wears ear protection and most importantly eye protection.

Hire a landscape maintenance company with INSURANCE and is bonded, licensed.  Once a year.  I just hired two wonderful older guys (each early 70's) who charged me $50 for one hour for the two machines to knock down bitterbrush and cheat grass...unbelievable how much they got done!  To be safe, try to hire someone with insurance.

Don't mow that swale.  I understand completely.  Nothing could stop me from doing everything. Now is a different story.  Just playing it smart and 'saving' the body I got left!